# Как сделать весь вывод одной функцией?

Tags: javascript, функции, dom

Есть скрипт, который загружает массив из api и выводит информацию в виде товаров в магазине. Есть кнопки сортировки, на которых висит обработчик событий, выводящий отсортированный список.

Как сделать весь вывод одной функцией? Потому что один и тот же код повторяется 3 раза.

Код выглядит так:

```
const marketURL = "https://fakestoreapi.com/products";

let stuff = await fetch(marketURL);
stuff = await stuff.json();

marketPlace.innerHTML = stuff.map(item => `
         <div id="mainCard" class="card m-2 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
            <img src="${item.image}" class="mx-auto card-img-top" title="${item.title}">
            <div class="card-body">
               <h5 class="card-title text-center">${item.title}</h5>
               <p class="card-text descript">${item.description}</p>
               <h4 class="text-end">$${item.price}</h4>
            </div>
         </div>
`).join("");

lowerP.addEventListener("click", function(){
    stuff.sort((a,b) => a.price > b.price ? 1 : -1);
    marketPlace.innerHTML = stuff.map(item => `
          <div id="mainCard" class="card m-2 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
            <img src="${item.image}" class="mx-auto card-img-top" title="${item.title}">
            <div class="card-body">
             <h5 class="card-title text-center">${item.title}</h5>
             <p class="card-text descript">${item.description}</p>
             <h4 class="text-end">$${item.price}</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
`).join("");
});

higherP.addEventListener("click", function(){
    stuff.sort((a,b) => a.price < b.price ? 1 : -1);
    marketPlace.innerHTML = stuff.map(item => `
             <div id="mainCard" class="card m-2 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
               <img src="${item.image}" class="mx-auto card-img-top" title="${item.title}">
               <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title text-center">${item.title}</h5>
                <p class="card-text descript">${item.description}</p>
                <h4 class="text-end">$${item.price}</h4>
               </div>  
            </div>
`).join("");
})
```

Comment: Забыл добавить код сортировки ```lowerP.addEventListener("click", function(){
    stuff.sort((a,b) => a.price > b.price ? 1 : -1);``` и после метода sort(), снова идет код, указанный в самом вопросе.

Comment: А где у вас дублирование то?

Comment: После того, как сработал обработчик события, вызывается сортировка массива, а после сортировки, снова идет код, указанный в вопросе. То есть, он повторяется 3 раза: при первоначальном выводе в ДОМ и в функциях в двух обработчиках

Comment: Но у вас в вопросе нет ни одной функции (если map не считать)

Comment: Кроме двух, анонимных - ("click", function(){}), внутрь которых я и вставляю вышеуказанный код с методом мар. А хотелось бы написать общую функцию, чтоб код не повторялся.

Comment: Ну так вынесите этот код в отдельную функцию и вызывайте после сортировки

Comment: Именно это у меня и не получается. Не могу "склеить" все вместе.

Comment: Тогда вам нужно добавить больше кода в вопрос, а то так не понятно, что у вас не получается. Почитайте [mcve]

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Сейчас дополню вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const marketURL = "https://fakestoreapi.com/products";

let stuff = await fetch(marketURL);
stuff = await stuff.json();

// Искомая функция
function printHtml() {
    marketPlace.innerHTML = stuff.map(item => `
         <div id="mainCard" class="card m-2 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
            <img src="${item.image}" class="mx-auto card-img-top" title="${item.title}">
            <div class="card-body">
               <h5 class="card-title text-center">${item.title}</h5>
               <p class="card-text descript">${item.description}</p>
               <h4 class="text-end">$${item.price}</h4>
            </div>
         </div>
`).join("");
}
// Первый вывод
printHtml();

lowerP.addEventListener("click", function(){
    stuff.sort((a,b) => a.price > b.price ? 1 : -1);
    // Просто её вызываем
    printHtml();
});

higherP.addEventListener("click", function(){
    stuff.sort((a,b) => a.price < b.price ? 1 : -1);
    // Просто её вызываем
    printHtml();
})
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Тот самый случай, когда самый очевидный вариант не пришел в голову. Что ж, буду приучаться начинать с очевидного.